# Proper login redirects for javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I currently have a page that is protected by a group that requires a login. the protected page has a redirect to a login page if the user is not logged in. How do I redirect the user back to the correct page if login is successful? currently I have it hard coded to the url in case the user accesses the login page directly. I was thinking of using history.go(-1); but if the user access the login directly after visiting a random website wouldn't that user just get directed to the wrong site?

Comment: The server should do the redirect, not the client. You can pass the target URL to the server as part of the login request.

Comment: Agreed, this should be done server-side. Every single incoming request to the server should be checked for a valid login session, and if there's no session, and the URL being requested requires one, then the script execution must stop (before it outputs any HTML or data) and the server should issue a header to redirect the user back to the login page. Client-side code can be interfered with by malicious users, in any case.